# Voice Search - Search Stack Exchange sites with your voice.

Tags: script

### Screenshot

[image]

### About

Does text-based searching frustrate you? Does the idea of commanding your browser to search for a phrase sound like fun? If so, this script may be for you. Just install it, click the little microphone icon in the search box, and start speaking!

#### License

[MIT License](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php)

#### Download

You can install this UserScript by clicking the link below:
http://files.quickmediasolutions.com/userscripts/voice_search.user.js

#### Platform

Unfortunately this script will only work on WebKit-based browsers (like Google Chrome). There are no plans to support other browsers.

### Contact

I can be contacted at `admin@quickmediasolutions.com`.

### Code

Written in JavaScript using jQuery.